# C# Socket doesn't disconnect properly

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, disconnect

I'm working on a server for the game *Minecraft*, which shows a dark-red screen when the player is disconnected. I'm disconnecting players like this:

```
Socket.Shutdown( SocketShutdown.Both );
Socket.Close();
```

I seem to be unable to write data after that, but the disconnected screen doesn't appear. It only appears when I completely terminate the server application, which indicates that the connection isn't closed at all.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

```
socket.BeginAccept( new AsyncCallback( AcceptClient ), null );

private void AcceptClient( IAsyncResult result )
    {
        try
        {
            // Initialize player
            Socket client = _socket.EndAccept( result );
```

.

```
Log( "Received unrecognized packet from " + player.IPAddress() + ", disconnecting client!" );

player.Disconnect();
_clients.Remove( player );
```

Comment: How do you detect disconnection in the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the API looks like for Minecraft, but odds are that there's a command you need to send to the client first, to let them know they've been disconnected.

Comment: There is, but what about disconnecting for using the wrong protocol? I don't understand why closing the application can make it happen, but my code can't.

Comment: One other thought: What socket are you disconnecting? Are you disconnecting the Listener or the one talking to the client? Maybe if you post more of your code, we could figure it out.

Comment: I'm disconnecting the client socket, but there is a possibility the client checks if the port is still open for the connection status.

Comment: Could you post some code, specifically the parts around the `Accept` call, and the stuff before the `Shutdown`?

Answer (score 0):

What about `Socket.Disconnect()` ?